# Unable to update/install packages in R 3.2.2 running on Google Compute Engine (Debian Wheezy )

Tags: r, debian, google-compute-engine

I have created a basic instance on Google Compute Engine running on Debian wheezy. My objective is to install R on an instance and access it remotely via Jupyter/Ipython notebook.

The problem I am facing is that once I install **R 3.2.2. "Fire Safety"** and I try to update the packages using `update.packages()`, I am unable to do so and I get a Warning stating: `unable to access index for repository https://cran.<rest of mirror address>` This is irrespective of which CRAN mirror I choose (18 mirror options). Similarly, if I try to install basic packages like **jsonlite** using `install.packages('jsonlite')` I get a similar error:

`Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘jsonlite’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)`. Again, this error is irrespective of the mirror I choose.

If it helps in any way for the diagnosis, the way I am installing R, right after a fresh instance is created, goes as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo -i
echo "deb http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cran.list
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install r-base-core r-base-dev
```

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this update/install package problem?

Answer (score 7):

Two quick ideas:

1. Replace the `https` with `http`, e.g. in `install.packages("digest", repos="http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu")`
2. Switch the repo to one where we know https is supported, e.g. `install.packages("digest", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")`

I can use the Berkeley host via both http and https, but maybe AWS blocks port 443?

Answer (score 0):

Via [an answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90229/67311):

> You need to install the package [`apt-transport-https`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-transport-https). Then you can use lines like
>
> ```
> deb https://some.server.com/debian stable main
> ```
>
> in your `sources.list` file.